# How do i add a legend for matplotlib which consists of the array index names instead of the values within the index?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, matplotlib

new to programming here.

I am trying to plot a graph based on a list, but the list arrays contain a series of values within them.
I am trying to use a for loop to plot all the categories into one graph. When I tried to plot the graph, everything went fine except for the legend. What I need to do is to create a legend which says which lines are the 'containers', 'freighters', 'bulk carriers'.... but when I tried to use plt.legend(), it gave me the values of 'containers', 'freighters', 'bulk carriers' instead of the labels itself. Can I have assistance as to how to plot just the list array instead of the values for the legend?

For additional clarification, here is one of the list values, specifically for containers only

```
Input: print(containers)

Output:
     month   vessel_type     number_of_vessels  gross_tonnage
0   2019-12   Container               1442      74170.533
8   2020-01   Container               1418      74664.129
16  2020-02   Container               1287      65183.106
24  2020-03   Container               1399      72789.161
32  2020-04   Container               1329      71068.988
40  2020-05   Container               1262      68167.275
48  2020-06   Container               1321      71659.294
56  2020-07   Container               1340      71578.085
```

````
categories=[containers,freighters,bulk_carriers,tankers,passengers,barges,tugs,miscellaneous]

for i in categories:
    plt.plot(i['month'],i['gross_tonnage'],label=i)
    plt.xlabel('months')
    plt.ylabel('gross_tonnage')
    plt.title('Changes in gross tonnage over time')
    plt.legend()```

[![Here is the screenshot of what im trying to achieve, pardon the poor drawing][1]][1]


[![this is the screenshot of the disaster][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai30L.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7knj8.png
````

Comment: What is freighters and bulk carriers here? You have shown only containers here and what are things inside categories?

Comment: it is similar to the container values just different numbers

Comment: hi i solved the issue by replacing the list with a dictionary instead